# I need to update a specific cell in an html table using only javascript, how do i target this cell?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So for an assignment I need to create a working shopping cart with remove function and if an article is already in the cart It should update the existing data when added again.

For instance I have the following cart.

Name:  Quantity: Price: Total:
Potato         1      1      1

This cart has been created as a table. So If I select another potato from a dropdown list it should update the current potato in the cart so the quantity becomes 2 and the total becomes 2. I have been looking for an answer to this problem for 4 hours now and I just can't seem to get any closer to the solution.

current code that adds items to the table:

```
"use strict";
const btn = document.getElementById('toevoegen');
const keuzeLijst = document.getElementById('groente');
const aantalArt = document.getElementById('aantal');
leesGroenten();

//leest de JSON file in
async function leesGroenten() {
    const response = await fetch("groenten.json")
    if (response.ok) {
        const groenten = await response.json();
        console.log(groenten);
        verwerkGroenten(groenten);
    } else {
        console.log("oeps er ging iets mis!");
    }
};

//Verwerkt de JSON file
function verwerkGroenten(groenten) {

    for (const groente of groenten) {
        voegGroentenToeAanLijst(groente);
    }
};

//Voegt de JSON file objecten toe aan de groente lijst
function voegGroentenToeAanLijst(groente) {
    let keuzeGroente = document.createElement("option");
    keuzeGroente.dataset.naam = groente.naam;
    keuzeGroente.dataset.prijs = groente.prijs;
    keuzeGroente.dataset.eenheid = groente.eenheid;
    keuzeGroente.dataset.aantal = 1;
    keuzeGroente.innerText = groente.naam + '(' + `${groente.prijs}` + "/" + `${groente.eenheid}` + ')';
    keuzeLijst.appendChild(keuzeGroente);

}

btn.onclick = controleLijst;

function controleLijst() {
    if (aantalArt.value === '' || aantalArt.value < 1) {
        document.getElementById('foutMelding').hidden = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('foutMelding').hidden = true;
    const groenteNaam = keuzeLijst.options[keuzeLijst.selectedIndex].dataset.naam;
    let gevondenListItem = vindListItemMetNaam(groenteNaam);
    if (gevondenListItem === null) {
        voegGroenteToeAanMandje(groenteNaam)
    } else {
        //Niet gevonden hoe ik cellen moet updaten
        voegGroenteToeAanMandje(groenteNaam)
        updateListItem(gevondenListItem)
    }
}
}
//Deze functie zoekt doorheen de tabel naar een artikel met de zelfde naam als het arikel 
//uit de keuze lijst.
function vindListItemMetNaam(groenteNaam) {
    const groenteNamen = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
    for (const groente of groenteNamen) {
        if (groente.id === groenteNaam) {
            return groente;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
//Deze functie zorgt dat een bestaand artikel wordt geupdate
function updateListItem() {
    console.log("bestaal al");

}
// Na een geslaagde controle wordt het artikel toegevoegd aan de tabel via onderstaande code
function voegGroenteToeAanMandje() {
    const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
    tbody.id = 'tabel'
    const tr = tbody.insertRow();
    tr.id = keuzeLijst.options[keuzeLijst.selectedIndex].dataset.naam
    const tdNaam = tr.insertCell();
    tdNaam.id = keuzeLijst.options[keuzeLijst.selectedIndex].dataset.naam
    tdNaam.innerText = keuzeLijst.options[keuzeLijst.selectedIndex].dataset.naam;
    const tdAantal = tr.insertCell();
    tdAantal.innerText = 1;
    tdAantal.id = 'aantal';
    const tdPrijs = tr.insertCell();
    tdPrijs.innerText = keuzeLijst.options[keuzeLijst.selectedIndex].dataset.prijs;
    tdPrijs.id = 'prijs'
    const tdTeBetalen = tr.insertCell();
    tdTeBetalen.innerText = tdPrijs.innerText;
    tdTeBetalen.id = 'te betalen';
    const verwijderTd = tr.insertCell();
    const verwijderHyperlink = document.createElement("img");
    verwijderHyperlink.src = "vuilbak.png"
    verwijderTd.appendChild(verwijderHyperlink);
    verwijderHyperlink.onclick = function () {
        const tr = this.parentElement.parentElement;
        tr.remove();
    }
};
```

and the html as requested

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="javascript.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>Groentenwinkel</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="groentenwinkel.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="groentenwinkel.css" />
  <script src="groentenwinkel.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="banner.jpg" id="banner" alt="banner">
  <h1>Bestelling</h1>
  <label>Groente:
    <select id="groente">
      <option value="">--- maak uw keuze ---</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>Aantal:
    <input id="aantal">
  </label>
  <button id="toevoegen">Toevoegen aan mandje</button>
  <button id="test">testknopje</button>
  <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Groente</th>
            <th>Aantal</th>
            <th>Prijs</th>
            <th>Te Betalen</th>
            <th>     </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="fout" hidden class="fout">Fout! Kies groente en aantal (minstens 1).</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have a function that checks if the selected item from the drop down list already appears in the table. But I have no idea how I can call a specific cell from a table to check this.

Lets say I choose potato

I then want to check if there is already an item in my table with the name potato and if so I want to update the quantity and total of that item.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Please share the HTML. See [mcve]

Comment: I added the html now. Sorry kind of new to stackoverflow

Comment: Do you want to check selected item vs `<th>`? Your ` <tbody>` is empty. Please add sample structure even if it's generated. You can use the snippet feature in editor to make a runnable demo

Comment: BTW ca't you keep `keuzeLijst.options[keuzeLijst.selectedIndex].dataset.name` in an array as you're creating them?

Comment: Hi, I editted my post. Now it contains my full javascript code. So basically what im doing is fetching objects (articles for the cart) from a json file. From these objects I fill up the table contents with the object data. Im pretty new to javascript and still learning so sorry if im not really clear. My native language is dutch so the code may contain some words u don't understand. But these are all variables, id's, dataproperties, etc... I could put the data in an array but I would have the same problem. Not knowing how to target a specific cell in a table.. Thanks for your effort btw

Comment: As far as I understand, you have a JSON response that already contains information about products. So you don't really have to look up table elements, you can process that data, for example count the same products in it and then render the table based on the processed data

Comment: If you really have to look up each row for some reason, it'd be something like `document.querySelector('tbody tr').forEach(tr => {});`

Comment: This is unfortuneatly not what I am looking for. When the above code gets executed it fills the select id:groente dropdown menu with the json data. Then It puts the selected data from the drop down menu in the table. What I need to do know is find a way to check if the selected data is already in the table and if so I need to be able to update the quantity and the price total of that data that is in the table. But its ok I will probably have a meet with my teacher to look at it together

Answer (score 0):

Since you set an unique ID (I hope) for `TR`, you can simply check it's existence and update it if already exists:

```js
"use strict";
const btn = document.getElementById('toevoegen');
const keuzeLijst = document.getElementById('groente');
const aantalArt = document.getElementById('aantal');
leesGroenten();

//leest de JSON file in
async function leesGroenten() {
/* changed */
//    const response = await fetch("groenten.json")
/* start temporary .json */
    const response = {
    ok: true,
    json: async () => {
        return [{
          naam: "naam 1",
          prijs: "prijs 1",
          eenheid : "eenheid 1"
        },
        {
          naam: "naam 2",
          prijs: "prijs 2",
          eenheid : "eenheid 2"
        }]
      }
    }
/* end temporary .json */
    if (response.ok) {
        const groenten = await response.json();
        console.log(groenten);
        verwerkGroenten(groenten);
    } else {
        console.log("oeps er ging iets mis!");
    }
};

//Verwerkt de JSON file
function verwerkGroenten(groenten) {
    for (const groente of groenten) {
        voegGroentenToeAanLijst(groente);
    }
};

//Voegt de JSON file objecten toe aan de groente lijst
function voegGroentenToeAanLijst(groente) {
    let keuzeGroente = document.createElement("option");
    keuzeGroente.dataset.naam = groente.naam;
    keuzeGroente.dataset.prijs = groente.prijs;
    keuzeGroente.dataset.eenheid = groente.eenheid;
    keuzeGroente.dataset.aantal = 1;
    keuzeGroente.innerText = groente.naam + '(' + `${groente.prijs}` + "/" + `${groente.eenheid}` + ')';
    keuzeLijst.appendChild(keuzeGroente);

}

btn.onclick = controleLijst;

function controleLijst() {
    if (aantalArt.value === '' || aantalArt.value < 1) {
        document.getElementById('foutMelding').hidden = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('foutMelding').hidden = true;
    const groenteNaam = keuzeLijst.options[keuzeLijst.selectedIndex].dataset.naam;
    let gevondenListItem = vindListItemMetNaam(groenteNaam);
    if (gevondenListItem === null) {
        voegGroenteToeAanMandje(groenteNaam)
    } else {
        //Niet gevonden hoe ik cellen moet updaten
        voegGroenteToeAanMandje(groenteNaam)
        updateListItem(gevondenListItem)
    }
}
}
//Deze functie zoekt doorheen de tabel naar een artikel met de zelfde naam als het arikel 
//uit de keuze lijst.
function vindListItemMetNaam(groenteNaam) {
    const groenteNamen = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
    for (const groente of groenteNamen) {
        if (groente.id === groenteNaam) {
            return groente;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
//Deze functie zorgt dat een bestaand artikel wordt geupdate
function updateListItem() {
    console.log("bestaal al");

}
// Na een geslaagde controle wordt het artikel toegevoegd aan de tabel via onderstaande code
function voegGroenteToeAanMandje() {
/* changed */
    const tbody = document.getElementById("tabel");
/* id is set in HTML already */
//    tbody.id = 'tabel'

/* check if TR with this id already exists */
    const exist = document.getElementById(keuzeLijst.options[keuzeLijst.selectedIndex].dataset.naam);
/* set tr to already existed row or if it doesn't exist insert a new one */
    const tr = exist || tbody.insertRow();
    tr.id = keuzeLijst.options[keuzeLijst.selectedIndex].dataset.naam;
/* this will be used to check existance of columns, this method is shorter than alternative: if (exist) ... else ... */
    var child = 0;
/* get existing cell or insert new one */
    const tdNaam = tr.children[child++] || tr.insertCell();
/* do you really need an ID here? */
//    tdNaam.id = keuzeLijst.options[keuzeLijst.selectedIndex].dataset.naam
    tdNaam.innerText = keuzeLijst.options[keuzeLijst.selectedIndex].dataset.naam;
    const tdAantal = tr.children[child++] || tr.insertCell();
    tdAantal.innerText = 1;
/* don't use same IDs on multiple elements */
//    tdAantal.id = 'aantal';
    const tdPrijs = tr.children[child++] || tr.insertCell();
    tdPrijs.innerText = keuzeLijst.options[keuzeLijst.selectedIndex].dataset.prijs;
/* don't use same IDs on multiple elements */
//    tdPrijs.id = 'prijs'
    const tdTeBetalen = tr.children[child++] || tr.insertCell();
    tdTeBetalen.innerText = tdPrijs.innerText;
/* don't use same IDs on multiple elements */
//    tdTeBetalen.id = 'te betalen';
/* since this is "static" cell, we don't need update it if it's already exists */
    if (!exist)
    {
      const verwijderTd = tr.insertCell();
      const verwijderHyperlink = document.createElement("img");
      verwijderHyperlink.src = "vuilbak.png"
      verwijderTd.appendChild(verwijderHyperlink);
      verwijderHyperlink.onclick = function () {
          const tr = this.parentElement.parentElement;
          tr.remove();
      }
    }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="javascript.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>Groentenwinkel</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="groentenwinkel.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="groentenwinkel.css" />
  <script src="groentenwinkel.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="banner.jpg" id="banner" alt="banner">
  <h1>Bestelling</h1>
  <label>Groente:
    <select id="groente">
      <option value="">--- maak uw keuze ---</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>Aantal:
    <input id="aantal">
  </label>
  <button id="toevoegen">Toevoegen aan mandje</button>
  <button id="test">testknopje</button>
  <table id="tabel">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Groente</th>
            <th>Aantal</th>
            <th>Prijs</th>
            <th>Te Betalen</th>
            <th>     </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="fout" hidden class="fout">Fout! Kies groente en aantal (minstens 1).</div>

<!-- added start -->
<div id="foutMelding">No clue what this is for</div>
<!-- added end -->

</body>

</html>
```

I've added `/* comments */` through out the code.

P.S.
Since you are asking in english, next time please provide code in english, it's very difficult read and understand your code.